# What do you call this function in PHP?

Tags: php, function

I was working on a project and I saw this function. I searched for it and could not find the right term and explanation.

```
<?php 
  $a = 'printf';
  $a("hello");
?>
```

The variable **$a** is a string and already has the value. The **a()** function output the arguments and not the stored value. Can you tell me what do you call this function in php?
Thanks.

Edited: 
I edited the code. This one worked for me,too.

Comment: $str is a string as you defined, which you cannot called as a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have noted this will produce an error if there is no function with the name of the value stored in $str.

The use of this is called a [variable function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).

Answer (score 1):

It will not give you any output.Instead of that it will produce a fatal error

```
"Call to undefined function This is my string()"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats not a function, your program will output

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function This is my string()`

correct way to do it would be

```
$str = "printf";
$word = "Hello World";
$str($word);
```

Comment: Still the wrong way - `print` is not a function either.

Comment: $DevZer0: no, it worked fine for me.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks, i think i got my perl and php mixed up. Sorry

Comment: $DevZer0: Can you take a look at the edited code, please?